# The container color that I am passing is not wrapping the title of MediumTopAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Here's what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

```kotlin
Scaffold(

        topBar = {
            MediumTopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.mediumTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Yellow
                ),
                // modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                title = { Text(text = "Expense")}

            )
        },

        content = { innerPadding ->

            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                Text(text = "Expenses")
            }

        }

    )
```

Even the fillMaxHeight wasnt able to alter the height of the container color that is shown in the image.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I misinterpreted the documentation. I added a new answer, I hope this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug described on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250838918). It should be resolved in recent versions of the `material3` dependency. Please update your dependency to the latest stable release:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1"
```

Let me know if that resolves the issue.